# Connect c wire at old furnace

Tags: common-wire

[image]I don’t have an air conditioner and have the same issue. Blue wire for c at thermostat but blue wire not connected to anything at old furnace. The blue wire is with a red wire and a beige wire near on switch (looks like light switch) Then there are bundles of wires at each of 2 small boxes. Those wires are red black and yellow.
Looked at other similar questions but my layout seems to be different. Any help appreciated
[image]

Comment: Connected at one place but not the other. Not sure what need to do with the unconnected blue wire

Comment: Can you post photos of how your actual thermostat is wired? Also, does the cable from the transformer (lump in the second photo) run off to the aquastat (box with its cover removed in the first photo), to the thermostat, or somewhere else?